# asp.net core razor view output quots problem

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, editor, razorengine

I want to show my texteditor content on razor view it contains html tags and it saved on database but when i run my website its look like a string value look at the cod and result. this is the value stored on database :

[image]

Now on razor view

```
<div class="container">
   div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
           @Model.Specification
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and finlay out out on browser is :
[image]

and when i debug i see this:

[image]

i try many ways by many browsers but result is same i dont khow whts the problem
id did this before in other project by php using ehco and it works fine but i dont khow why on asp it doesnt work can anyone help me???i just want normal view i mean tags show like html tags not like string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
@Html.Raw(Model.Specification)

// or

@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Specification))
```